# Jcomments doesn't work with Virtuemart properly

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

How can I see name of Product in comments list? The "Article name" field in JComment is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can find here integration of JComments with Virtuemart depend on their versions:

- [jcomments-virtuemart old](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=99683.0)
- [VirtueMart 2.0.3c+ - JComments 2.3.0 Integration (Free). For J 1.7 and 2.5](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=99683.0)

I hope this will help you, let me know if it doesn't work.